# mate-terminal - start in new PID

Tags: gnome-terminal

I often like to kill a set of terminal instances by process id but mate-terminal (which I believe to be a fork of gnome-terminal) will run a number of windows under the same PID. This is not always true and I haven't noticed what determines it,but the outcome is that if I kill a PID I will kill some windows that I don't want to kill.

As a fix, I'd like to tell terminal to start with a new process, but I don't see that option in the terminal man page. Have I missed something? Or perhaps there is a bash command that can force this.

Comment: What is about `mate-terminal --window`?

Comment: @N0rbert No. The same PID unfortunately. I can understand why that is and should be default behavior, but the option is offered by other applications eg.geany.

Comment: "I often like to kill a set of terminal instances" – not a typical user behavior :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you're looking for is `--disable-factory`.

Comment: From `man mate-terminal`: "--disable-factory" has "Do not register with the activation nameserver, do not re-use an active terminal".

Comment: And that's something *gnome-terminal* doesn't seem to offer. *konsole* has `--separate` which does the same thing.

Comment: For gnome-terminal it's a bit more cumbersome but still doable: you have to manually fire up a server using a custom `--app-id`, followed by the client with the same option.